# Impress.js + Firefox: How to disable advance slide on mouse click

Tags: javascript, firefox, impress.js

Impress.js works great in Chrome, but unfortunately, it's somewhat buggy in Firefox.  The biggest problem that I am having is that, in Firefox, the slideshow advances to the next slide on every mouse click.  Does anybody know of a way to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to js/impress.js, delete the code below (about line 783~797) , it listen the click event:

```
    // Delegated handler for clicking on step elements
    document.addEventListener( "click", function( event ) {
        var target = event.target;

        // Find closest step element that is not active
        while ( !( target.classList.contains( "step" ) &&
                  !target.classList.contains( "active" ) ) &&
                  ( target !== document.documentElement ) ) {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }

        if ( api.goto( target ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false );
```